# How to define a schema with 'NumberLong' or 'NumberInt' type when use mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Now I use mongoose to define a schema like below:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    roleId:Number,
    type:Number,
    _id:false
});
```

What I actually want to fulfill is to create a document whose field ***roleId***'s type is NumberLong and field ***type***'s type is NumberInt. However, the new document's fields created with this schema are all with 
 type of NumberInt.

After reading the mongoose's docs, I still have no idea to define schema with different number types.

So, if there is any solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

SchemaType stores a number value, with restrictions. Mongoose does not natively support long and double datatypes for example, although MongoDB does. However, Mongoose can be extended using plugins to support these other types.

You can use "mongoose-long" npm for the purpose.

Comment: Its a duplicate question and already been addressed in the comment. Do not answer duplicated questions, just flag them.